# Why do we need semicolon before closing brace?

Tags: c++, grammar

In C++, why do we need semicolon before closing brace? It's strange that something like

```
{
    statement;
    statement;
    statement
}
```

is not possible, that semicolon not only delimiter statements. I understand that semicolon after class definition is necessary because there may be a definition of objects of this class. But what's up here?

Comment: Because of the way statement is defined in grammar. Simple as that.

Comment: Why introduce a special rule for a statement preceding a closing brace?

Comment: Every time you added a statement you would have to remember to go back and add the missing semi-colon from the preceding one. It would look inconsistent. It would mean making the compiler slightly more complicated than it already is.

Comment: No, it's not "strange".

Comment: C++11 has already an awfully complex syntax (notably for historical reasons). No reason to make it even more complex!

Comment: @Galik *et al.* Using `;` as a separator instead of a terminator actually makes a compiler very slightly simpler.

Comment: How is this opinion-based? Separators versus terminators is a well-researched topic, and the issue was settled well before ANSI C was standardized in 1989.

Comment: @MSalters I agree with Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how the C++ grammar is defined. A semicolon is used to transform an expression into a statement:

```
statement = expression ';'
```

For example:

```
a = 1;
```

The `a = 1` is an expression, put an extra `;` and you have a statement that can be executed.

Likewise, a variable or type declaration must be ended with a semicolon:

```
struct S { int x; };
```

However, functions definitions and block statements do not end with `;`:

```
int main() {}
```

You may be surprised because you have a Pascal background. In Pascal, the semicolon is used to separate statements, so you do not need the last one. However, if you want to write 2 successive block statements, in C++ you write `{...} {...}` while in Pascal you need the semicolon: `begin ... end; begin ... end`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a well-known distinction in programming language theory, terminators versus separators. If the semicolon would have been a separator, you wouldn't need that last one. C choose to use terminators and C++ inherited that, Pascal uses separators

However, it turns out that terminators are the better choice. Programmers make less mistakes with terminators than they do with separators. (Gannon & Horning, *The impact of language design on the production of reliable software. Proceedings of the international conference on Reliable software* 1975).

Answer (score 2):

C++ uses `;` to determine an end of a statement.

For example you can write code like this

```
Statement;statement;statement;
```

The `{ }` indicates the scope of your current statement.

For example:

```
  { int a(0);} //a "dies" at the } 
  a = 1; //error a is not found in current scope
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that the compiler expects every line of code to end with a semicolon. Without this it cannot determine the statement.

Comment: This is just a circular argument.

Answer (score 0):

It is needed so that the compiler knows when to stop executing that line of code. Even if it is the last line of code before a closing brace.

Imagine you are writing an essay. Do you leave your last sentence of every paragraph without a fullstop? Make any sense?

Comment: Nice argument, but in Python, it makes)

Comment: It is also legal in Pascal.